# lower the bounds of regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I've created this expression

```
(?<=&lt;)(.+?)(&lt;|&gt;)(.+?)(?=&gt;)
```

I thought it would caught `&lt;` or `&gt;` that are located between `&lt;` and `&gt;`.

However for example in that case

```
&lt;#freemarker &lt; template&gt;
```

It's caught

```
#freemarker &lt; template
```

instead of just `&lt;`.

Ideally I want it to caught those `&lt;` and `&gt;` that are located between `&lt;#` or `&lt;/#` and `&gt;`.

What should be changed in order to make it work properly?

Comment: Could you clarify please? What is the environment/language you are using?

Comment: Oh! Sorry forgot to add `java` tag

Comment: What is the average length of the input string?

Comment: What makes you think you can actually get a single one per match? Well, you can't. You have to match it like you tried, except with greedy quantifier's. You capture the contents with a simple regex, then use another regex to pick out substrings in the content. No need to make a mountain out of a mole hill.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest leveraging Java constrained-width look-behind if you really need to match just the `&lt;` or `&gt;`:

```
(?s)(?<=&lt;/?#.{0,1000})(?:&lt;|&gt;)(?=.*?&gt;)
```

[Demo](http://www.ocpsoft.org/tutorials/regular-expressions/java-visual-regex-tester/):

With this approach, it is assumed that the string after the initial `&lt;/?#` is not longer than 1000, which should be enough for a real-case scenario.

Here is an [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/D6PXIG):

```
String s = "&lt;#freemarker &lt; template&gt;";
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s.split("(?s)(?<=&lt;/?#.{0,1000})(?:&lt;|&gt;)(?=.*?&gt;)")));
}
```

Result: `[&lt;#freemarker ,  template&gt;]`

Comment: Could anyone please explain the downvote? Just for the fun of it?

Comment: Trying to sell the `.{0,1000}` part without and instead of explaining the actual limitations that java regexes face when confronted with problems similar to the one in OP's question?

Comment: @ndn: With this approach, it is assumed that the string after the initial `&lt;/?#` is not longer than 1000, which should be enough for a real-case scenario.

Answer (score 0):

In Java you can always use `Matcher` method [`start(int group)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#start%28int%29) and [`end(int group)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#end%28int%29), to get indices of part you are interested in. So just use:

```
(?<=&lt;)(?:.+?)(&lt;|&gt;)(?:.+?)(?=&gt;)
```

and, then `matcher.group(1)` to get matched string, or `matcher.start(1)` and `matcher.end(1)` to get beginning and ending index of matched fragment in string. The `?:` are for avoiding to capture fragments you don't want to capture in groups.

Example in Java:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String example = "&lt;#freemarker &lt; template&gt;";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=&lt;)(?:.+?)(&lt;|&gt;)(?:.+?)(?=&gt;)");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(example);
        while(matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(example.substring(matcher.start(1), matcher.end(1)));
        }
    }
}
```